# Concatenate csv files in powershell, without the first line (except for the first file)

Tags: powershell

I have multiple *.csv files. I want to concatenate them into a single CSV file in a powershell script. All csv files have the same header (the first line), so when I concatenate them I want to keep the first line only from the first file.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: The solution in **this answer intentionally uses *plain-text processing*** to process the files, for two reasons:

- Use of `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` incurs significant processing overhead (though that may not matter in a given situation); **plain-text processing is significantly faster**.
- **In Windows PowerShell and PowerShell [Core] 6.x, the output will invariably have *double-quoted* column values**, even if they weren't initially (though that should normally not matter).

  - In PowerShell [Core] 7.0+ `Export-Csv` and `ConvertTo-Csv` now have a `-UseQuotes` parameter that allows you to control quoting in the output.

That said, **`Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` are certainly the better choice whenever you need to *read and interpret* the data** (as opposed to just copying it elsewhere) - see [Sid's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60170636/45375).

---

```
# The single output file.
# Note: Best to save this in a different folder than the input
#       folder, in case you need to run multiple times.
$outFile = 'outdir/out.csv'

# Get all input CSV files as an array of file-info objects,
# from the current dir. in this example
$inFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv)

# Extract the header line (column names) from the first input file
# and write it to the output file.
Get-Content $inFiles[0] -First 1 | Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 $outFile

# Process all input files and append their *data* rows to the
# output file (that is, skip the header row).
# NOTE: If you only wanted to extract a given count $count of data rows
#       from each file, add -First ($count+1) to the Get-Content call.
foreach ($file in $inFiles) {
  Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
    Add-Content -Encoding Utf8 $outFile 
}
```

<sup>Note the use of `-Encoding Utf8` as an example; adjust as needed; by default, `Set-Content` will use "ANSI" encoding in Windows PowerShell, and BOM-less UTF-8 in PowerShell *Core*.</sup>

*Caveat*: By doing line-by-line plain-text processing, you're relying on each *text line* representing a single CSV *data row*; this is *typically* true, but doesn't have to be.

Conversely, if performance is paramount, the plain-text approach above could be made significantly faster with direct use of .NET methods such as [`[IO.File]::ReadLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines#System_IO_File_ReadLines_System_String_) or, if the files are small enough, even [`[IO.File]::ReadAllLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines#System_IO_File_ReadAllLines_System_String_).

Answer (score 2):

You could have done like this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.csv).FullName | Import-Csv | Export-Csv $path\concatenated.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Where `$path` is the folder where the csv files exist. The final csv file will be in the same folder.

Comment: If performance and preserving the quoting status of the fields aren't a concern, this is certainly the most convenient option. I suggest mentioning that explicit use of `-Encoding` may be needed on output, given that (a) the input encoding isn't preserved (it never is in PowerShell) and (b) `Export-Csv` defaults to ASCII(!) in Windows PowerShell, which can lead to data loss. As an aside: the `.FullName` workaround is fortunately no longer needed in PowerShell [Core] v6.2.3+.